# DNS server not resolving github page properly after two days

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, github

I had GitHub pages set up at `mypage.github.io`. I changed it to `mynewpage.github.io` with a new account and repository.

I deleted the old CNAME and configured another CNAME in DNSimple to point to the new location:

```
CNAME    www.example.com    mynewpage.github.io
```

Now when I run `dig www.example.com` in the terminal it returns

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.example.com.        3600    IN  CNAME   mynewpage.github.io.
```

But when I visit the domain `www.example.com` directly in the browser it still shows the old page at `mypage.github.io` instead of the page at `mynewpage.github.io`.

I thought it might be the ISP caching or something, but it has persisted for two days now and on different machines in different locations.  What needs to change?

Comment: did you try interrogating a DNS (e.g. with `host`, `dig` or `nslookup`) to see what it actually returns? using a browser to test a DNS leaves many doubts about what can be actually wrong.

Comment: Have you ensured everything in the DNS is okay? intodns.com is generally a good place to look to see if things are broken or not. 

It's a lot easier to troubleshoot with the actual domain, since the problem is specific to your configuration. If you can't find an error through intodns, have you tried it from a proxy? If not, do you want to share your domain so we can look at it as well?

Comment: Do you have an actual *reason* for obscuring your domain name? You might get quicker and better results if you include it. See also http://meta.serverfault.com/a/6063.

Comment: @Ale yes I did a `dig` and it returns the new CNAME record, see the middle of the question above.  Edit: `host`, `dig`, and `nslookup` all point to the new CNAME record (`mynewpage.github.io`)

Comment: Did you try then using another browser, or completely clearing the browser's cache?

Comment: @Ale, yes I have tried it in separate browsers, separate machines, and through a proxy. No difference; everything shows old page...

Comment: Is it possible that github hasn't properly updated the change?

Comment: @tyler If the DNS entry is ok and you observe the problem from multiple machines, the issue might indeed be on github. Did you double check the config on github side? (see https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/)

Comment: @Ale yes it looks like the problem is likely that I had to delete the previous CNAME file in the old repository... go figure.  https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-cname-file-to-your-repository/.  If you want to write up as an answer I'll accept it.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the information on the DNS seems to be ok (see output from `dig`), and the issue is visible from different machines, the problem has to be on the other side, i.e., on GitHub. Make sure that the configuration on that side is correct (see https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/ for info about how to correctly configure a custom domain name).